# Run pgbench on postgreSQL database hosted in Google Cloud

Tags: postgresql, powershell, google-cloud-platform

I have a PostgreSQL database instance setup in my google cloud platform.
I want to create a script that can execute pgbench on this database, preferably from windows powershell, on my local machine.
To do this I installed the GoogleCloud SDK, and can connect to the database using 'gcloud sql connect'.
PostgreSQL is install on my windows machine.
However, even after successful login, it cant seem to find the pgbench command.
When I try to execute pgbench, I get the following:

```
pgbench -i -s 50 master;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pgbench"
LINE 1: pgbench -i -s 50 master;
```

The database in question is named master.
The pgbench tool is available directly in my powershell, but I cant seem to get it to run on the remote instance.

Further, if I access the Cloud shell in GCP, execute the same

> gcloud sql connect

I get connected to the database, but still no pgbench.
So, even to get pgbench to run from anywhere on said database, would be a help.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, Im pretty new to GCP and at  the moment I'm pretty lost. I will do my best to add info as i go and make this useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

The command you show opens a connection with some client tool (probably `psql`, but I'm not going to pay to test this).  `pgbench` is a binary, you need to run it from the OS command line, not from inside the client tool.  You should configure your cloud SQL instance so it permanently accepts connections from your machine, rather than using `gcloud sql connect` to temporarily creates a constrained connection/tunnel.  There are [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#configure-instance-mysql) for allowing direct connections.  Note that pgbench and psql both connect using the libpq library, so the methods for connection that works for one will work for the other.